# %TYPE in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Can we make parameter of a procedure of same type as that of data type of a column in a table in SQL SERVER ?

In Oracle we can do it as follow:

```
myVar IN mySchema.myTable.myColumn%TYPE
```

Comment: There is no eqivalent of this oracle feature in SQL Server.

Comment: @MitchWheat - It is true. UDTs aren't the same thing. Changing the definition of UDTs is a real pain compared to just dynamically inferring it from the column datatype.

Comment: @MitchWheat: i get it, your solution works, but it's hardly "the same thing"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of this Oracle feature in SQL Server.

Whilst not exactly the same thing, SQL Server 2005 onwards you can use [CREATE TYPE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and  declare the column and the parameter of the same User Defined Type (UDT):

> Creates an alias data type or a user-defined type in the current
>   database. The implementation of an alias data type is based on a SQL
>   Server native system type. A user-defined type is implemented through
>   a class of an assembly in the Microsoft .NET Framework common language
>   runtime (CLR). To bind a user-defined type to its implementation, the
>   CLR assembly that contains the implementation of the type must first
>   be registered in SQL Server by using CREATE ASSEMBLY.

An example:

```
CREATE TYPE SSN
FROM varchar(11) NOT NULL ;
```

[**BUT**, I very rarely create user defined types in SQL Server, for the same reasoning as mentioned by @Martin Smith: "Changing the definition of UDTs is a real pain compared to just dynamically inferring it from the column datatype."]

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment on their reasoning. I've done my best to answer the question